# How to install a git plugin on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm completely new to Rails and just installed Rails 3 on Ubuntu 10.04. I was wondering if someone could please explain how to install a plugin from a Git repository.

More specifically, I'm trying to install the restful-authentication plugin from the git repository: git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oops. sorry everyone. just found the answer:

rails plugin install git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git

Comment: i got errors when i ran it. i did find a mod made specifically for Rails 3 though.. use:

rails plugin install git://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication ...followed by...
 git clone git://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication ...to generate the structure you should then run... rails g authenticated user sessions --include-activation ...and the console/website will give you instructions on how to edit your files.